# How do i remove a text from an integer that is inside an html tag?

Tags: html, web, integer, screen-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape and I came across a data that I need. The data is a couple of numbers but it has a few strings trailing it. My problem is, how do I remove the text from the integer? For example:

`<a> 7,407 people voted </a>`

I just want the number alone. I've tried slicing it but it messes with some numbers that are bigger or smaller than the above example.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim() function to remove spaces, then apply split() to convert the string into an array, and finally, retrieve the first element.

```js
" 7,407 people voted ".trim().split(" ")[0]
```